# How can i obtain an access token from Graph explorer using C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

I am trying to obtain an access token from graph explorer using the following code:

```
string clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
string tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID";

IConfidentialClientApplication app = 
    ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithClientSecret("YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET")
        .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
        .Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();

string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine($"Access token: {accessToken}");
```

The issue is that the `accessToken` here is shorter than what I get when I login to Graph explorer. Also the scope is set to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, but I want to be able to send messages to teams, so I need to add the scopes `Team.ReadBasic.All Channel.ReadBasic.All ChannelMessage.Send Chat.ReadWrite`.

How can I do this using C#?

Answer (score 0):

`AcquireTokenForClient` means you are using client credential flow. According this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/client-credential-flows#scopes-to-request

> The scope to request for a client credential flow is the name of the resource followed by /.default. This notation tells Microsoft Entra ID to use application level permissions declared statically during the application registration.

Unlike other flows, you cannot specify scopes in the request in client credential flow. You have to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` and configure other scopes in the Azure app registration like below:
[image]

Comment: I have confiured an app in azure with those api permissions and still my token is not correct ?

Comment: its basically the access_token that i can see in graph explorer , how can i get that in a c# app ?